# C++ How to Catch a Exception Thrown by a Thread in Boost from the Thread-Spawning Function

Tags: c++, boost, exception, boost-thread

I have a C++ application in which I use Boost Threads to provide concurrency. The basic sample is as follows:

```
processingThreadGroup->create_thread(boost::bind(process, clientSideSocket, this));
```

Here, processingThreadGroup is a shared pointer to a thread pool in boost, and process is the function that I need to call. The clientSideSocket and this are parameters that should be passed to the process function.

Inside the process function, I throw a custom Exception if an error is detected. The process function sends data to a remote server. So my question is, how to I propagate this error up the call stack? I want to shut down the system after a clean up. Tried the following:

```
try {
    processingThreadGroup->create_thread(boost::bind(process, clientSideSocket, this));
} catch (CustomException& exception) {
    //code to handle the error
}
```

But didn't work. Any idea on how to do this properly?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks a lot like what `std::async` _does/may do_, which uses `future`s to handle return values and exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To propagate return values and exceptions you should use `future`s. Here is a simple way to do it:

```
// R is the return type of process, may be void if you don't care about it
boost::packaged_task< R > task( boost::bind(process, clientSideSocket, this) );
boost::unique_future< R > future( task.get_future() );

processingThreadGroup->create_thread(task);

future.get();
```

This has a number of gotchas that you have to keep in mind. First, the lifetime of `task` has to extend the *asynchronous* execution of `process`. Second, `get()` will block until the `task` is finished and return its value if it ended successfully, or propagate the exception if one was thrown. You can use all kind of functions to check the state of the `future`, like `has_value()`, `has_exception()`, `is_ready()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm new to boost and will read on futures.

Comment: @Izza: The code you posted is not real code, is it? The `bind` call will be trying to make a _copy_ of the socket...

Comment: clientSideSocket is just an integer to identify the socket. So I don't think it is an issue.